# Bootstrap 4 modal not loading only giving faded screen

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-4, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

I am trying to load a bootstrap modal on a button click.

Already I am have one more Modal in the page which is working fine but on the button click but when I am trying to load another modal on a button click, its just loading faded screen.

```
<button class="btn btn-green btn-sm" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#addUserModal"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> <span>Add User</span></button>

<!-- Add User Modal -->
          <div class="modal fade" id="addUserModal" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="addUserModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
              <!-- Modal content-->
              <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                  <h6 class="modal-title">Add User</h6>
                  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                  <form action="" method="POST">
                    <div class="input-group mb-3">
                      <div class="input-group-prepend">
                        <span class="input-group-text">User ID</span>
                      </div>
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="user_id" value="{{user.UserID}}">
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-group mb-3">
                  </form>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
              </div>
            </div>    
          </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could it be that there is a mistake in your -tags? That may cause an error in your modal-body.

```
<div class="modal-body">
              <form action="" method="POST">
                <div class="input-group mb-3">
                  <div class="input-group-prepend">
                    <span class="input-group-text">User ID</span>
                  </div>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="user_id" value="{{user.UserID}}">
                </div>
                //removed orphan tag
              </form>
            </div>
```

When removed, the modal works fine.

Comment: Yes Mr. Charles, the problem was with tags. I resolved it now its working fine. Thank you sir.

Answer (score 0):

The code you posted is working fine

[Codepen Link](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/jdYjqV)

Make sure you have added the `jquery`, `popper.js`.

Comment: Ya bro the code is working fine thanks for the help.